# Linux: Copy all files recursively by extension to single dirrectory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cp

I am trying to copy all `*.tif` files from ./old to the ./new. In ./old i have lots of subdirs with different files, and in ./new i need only TIF files, without folder tree.

So, I tried

```bash
cp -vR ./old/*.TIF ./new`
```

But got the error:

```
No such file or directory "./old/*.TIF"
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: bash is case-sensitive so using `.TIF` when it is actually `.tif` will fail

Comment: Out of curiosity: what would you like to happen if there are files w/ identical names in different subdirectories? Last one found wins, the others don't make it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use find for this `find . -name "*.TIF" -exec cp {} new \;`

So `find` is used to find files. The command is saying `find` files starting from here `.` where the name of the file `-name` ends in `.tif` remember the double quotes for shell expansion. So to find all the `tif` files is simply.

```
find . -name "*.tif"
./2/3/3.tif
./2/2.tif
./1.tif
```

We then use `-exec` to do something with files in this case `cp` found files `{}` to the target directory `new` followed by an escaped semicolon `\;`

Answer (score 3):

It should be like this. You have to enter old directory:

```
cd old
cp -R *.tif ../new
```

Answer (score 0):

You might not have any `.tif` files in the `old` directory.

Moreover you can get a list of files and copy them using a simple script:

`find /old -type f | xargs grep *.tif`
will give you the list.

You can do this:

```
for i in `find /old -type f | xargs grep *.tif` 
do
cp $i /new
done;
```